# Is there a way to extract the generic type of Array type from interface properties?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have something like this.
I want to take `number | string` part out of the objects property in `A`, and reuse it in `B`.

```js
interface A {
  objects: Array<number | string>
}

interface B{
          // I want to extract this part from the objects of the "A" interface
  object: number | string  
}
```

I can think of something like this

```js
type ObjectType = number | string

interface A {
  objects: Array<ObjectType>
}

interface B{
  object: ObjectType
}
```

But what I am really looking for is something like this

```js
interface A {
  objects: Array<number | string>
}

interface B{
          // I am making this up, but is there something like this in Typescript??
  object: ExtractType<A, "objects">
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can infer the item type of an array with help of [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type ArrayItemType<T extends Array<any>> = T extends Array<infer I> ? I : any

interface A {
  objects: Array<number | string>
}

interface B{
  // (property) B.object: string | number
  object: ArrayItemType<A["objects"]>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCCAnRBDEUC8UmpAHgDsBXAWwCMJEoAfKAZ2EQEsCBzAPgChPRJtk0ASWAQSAFXAQ8YqBAAeIggBM6-XHhQEQ7dpigz5ilWrR4WAM0pRBugPzWoALiiaQ3XtDjDREvlhxCIuKSeHAB2tycLCKI5igAxtDwUADenFBQAPZkAFYQ8cB0zuGEpBRUtAzMbFwAvtzRlHGJUABCaRmdXVAA9D0OKCRQJCgA1iysUMAAFkyqRGAANFBkRMBQc1PTlNB0mSQQMxNQADZMo9BHqiz6knTxzGDAtrbpWbn5wMUCIN7BkHh4ABtABE2TyBToIIAunVOEA)